PowerShell WinSCP .NET Assembly GetFiles – "Timeout waiting for WinSCP to respond"
I'm having an odd issue following the $session.GetFiles command on the documentation page itself of GetFiles for .NET Assembly on Powershell.
When I take away the ClientFolder in the source directory (first argument of $session.GetFiles), it will give it a timeout error "Timeout waiting for WinSCP to respond". When I put the ClientFolder back in, it will run and retrieve the files needed within the subdirectories.
Why? Is there a recursion limit for subdirectories for it to look through? It has only a few levels of subdirectories between the requested FileMask files and the ClientFolder. I don't see the problem.
# Connect
$session.Open($sessionOptions)

#
$transferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions
$transferOptions.FileMask = "*Finance.xlsx"

# Download files
$transferOptions.AddRawSettings("ExcludeEmptyDirectories", "1")
$session.GetFiles("/CompanyName/HealthFiles/ClientFolder/*", "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\targetfolder\", $False, $transferOptions).Check()

This will run and return files successfully, but I want to delete the ClientFolder level and run it. I will timeout and now download any files if I do so...

This solved the error. Add a $session.Timeout:
# Connect
$session.Open($sessionOptions)
$session.Timeout = New-TimeSpan -Seconds 400

#
$transferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions
$transferOptions.FileMask = "*Finance.xlsx"

# Download files
$transferOptions.AddRawSettings("ExcludeEmptyDirectories", "1")
$session.GetFiles("/CompanyName/HealthFiles/*", "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\targetfolder\", $False, $transferOptions).Check()

